# Do logic on props after fetch with Redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i recently started to work with Redux in React.
I was wondering how to do some logic on data which i've just fetched (is it a bad practice?), in the same handler were i call the redux actions.
I attach a simple example so you can understand what i mean.

```
 function CakeContainer(props) {
   return (
      <div>
         <h2>Number of cakes - {props.numOfCakes}</h2>
         <button onClick={props.buyCake}>Buy Cake</button>
      </div>
   )

}
```

`props.buyCake` works fine, it fetches `numOfCakes` from the redux state and decreases by 1 the value, which is displayed in the component.
So if the value of `numOfCakes` at the beginning is 10, after click on the button, it will be 9.

What if i want to, for example, multiply the value of `numOfCake` inside the button handler?
The component code will be

```
function CakeContainer(props) {
   return (
      <div>
         <h2>Number of cakes - {props.numOfCakes}</h2>
         <button onClick={() => {
           props.buyCake();
           console.log("num multiplied by 2",props.numOfCakes*2)
         }}>Buy Cake</button>
      </div>
   )

}
```

In the console log, after the first click on the button i have 20 (10*2) because `NumOfCakes` is not updated yet.
Is there a way to have the updated value in the handler or is it a bad practice?

Comment: You could pass a callback to the buyCake, there in buyCake you could call that callback once you update the redux state. You can pass the latest redux state value to the callback in your buyCake to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please provide a code example? @MudasirZahoor

Comment: If you could post your code somewhere on codesandbox etc. I can help.

Comment: Here's the code :) https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-rubin-mww5q @MudasirZahoor

Comment: I've posted the answer below, let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Brilliant it does what i need. Thank you so much! @MudasirZahoor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a callback to the redux action in which you can get your latest state value. Here's a codesandbox for your use case

https://codesandbox.io/s/reduxexample-forked-dowuj

Alternatively, you could return a promise from your action and resolve the same to your cakeContainer.